# Output XML file, without saving

Tags: php, xml

I want to be able to create a XML File, add nodes and such to it, then output it to the screen without saving.

```
$bookxml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

is how i have the XML file created, however i just can't anyway to display the XML file on the screen without saving it.

However i am having a problem with outputting even in save, this is the line i have

```
echo $bookxml->save("testing.xml");
```

All this does is return the file size of the newly created XML, and not the contents.

Any help would be awesome, i'm completely stumped on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is [saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), additionally you can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to encode the xml so you can see it in your browser display.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($bookxml->saveXML());
```

Comment: That doesn't output everything just the contents of nodes, not the nodes themselves, for example rather than output
<course>CC140</course> it just outputs CC140 on the screen even though <course>CC140</course> is in the source

Comment: With that a giant blob comes out, no new lines for next node, just everything straight after the next, is there any way around that?

Comment: @CraigWeston try [`$bookxml->formatOuput = true;`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput)

Comment: I have formatOutput, but that doesn't do anything.

In the source code it is formatted perfectly, just on the screen its still a wall of text

Comment: @CraigWeston than wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You want the `saveXML` method, not the `save` method:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php